# How to get JUnit5 with JDK10 (jigsaw) and Maven3 to work?

Tags: java, maven-3, junit5, java-platform-module-system, java-10

I work with some friends on a jdk 10 application which use the jigsaw feature set (introduced in jdk9) and junit5 with maven as build-management.

But always if we try to run tests with Maven we get a InaccessibleObjectException
exception like:

```
[ERROR] resourceSchedule  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make de.truncated.framework.shared.resources.ResourceManagerTest() accessible: module de.truncated.framework.shared does not "opens de.truncated.framework.shared.resources" to unnamed module @ed7f8b4
```

I'm googling since days now ... in jdk9 it can be simply adressed with *--permit-illegal-access* but this it not possible in jdk10 because this flag was removed. And the jdk10 code examples from junit5 and others on github don't use jigsaw how it seems.

So it looks like I miss something major in the maven, module or jvm args config.
It would be very nice if someone could provide help on this matter.

Thank you very much!

**Some additional informations to the project which could be helpful:**

- the primary code is configured by a module info file which exports (not opens) to everyone (its a framework like code base)
- the test code is not modularized
- no jvm args are applied currently

used versions:

```
<properties>
   <java.version>10</java.version>
   <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <surefire.version>2.21.0</surefire.version>
   <asm.version>6.1.1</asm.version>
   <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
   <junit.platform.version>1.2.0</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
```

depencies:

```
    <!--
    junit 5 dependency
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

build plugins:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>${asm.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>${asm.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

full stacktrace:

```
[INFO] Running de.truncated.framework.shared.resources.ResourceManagerTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s <<< FAILURE! - in de.truncated.framework.shared.resources.ResourceManagerTest
[ERROR] singleThreadedResource  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make de.truncated.framework.shared.resources.ResourceManagerTest() accessible: module de.truncated.framework.shared does not "opens de.truncated.framework.shared.resources" to unnamed module @3af9c5b7
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:192)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:185)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:1332)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:429)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:185)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:358)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.prepare(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:89)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
```

Comment: Will be addressed by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-341

At the moment, you need to "--add-opens MODULE/PACKAGE=org.junit.platform.commons"

See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-modular-world/test-patch-runtime.jsh

Comment: Ok I will try that out if I'm back from the WeAreDevelopers Congress, thank you.

Comment: As a side note, `--permit-illegal-access` was not removed in JDK 10, since it wasn't present in JDK 9 GA. It was in some JDK 9 EA releases, but was replaced by [`--illegal-access=(permit|warn|debug|deny)`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Relaxed-strong-encapsulation), which is still available in JDK 10.

Comment: ok thank you for your hint @MarkReinhold  very appreciated !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Today I've found two solutions for that issue.

1) You may add --add-opens to surefire plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>--add-opens de.truncated.framework.shared/de.truncated.framework.shared.resources=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That will work because by default surefire plugin adds --add-reads to surefireargs file and JUnit5 uses reflection for which "reads" is not enough.

2) Alternatively you may mark all your JUnit5 test classes (and their annotated methods) as *public*. That will also help because in that case JUnit will not use reflection when running tests (well, at least it doesn't in version 5.3.1).

P.S. I used maven-compiler-plugin version 3.8.0 and maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M1.

Comment: Making test classes and methods public helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a (new) option in the Maven Surefire plugin called `useModulePath`. This option enables to use the traditional Java 8 class path instead of the module path and ignores a `module-info.class` not turning on the Java module mode, i.e. all classes on the class path can be used.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--  allow to use unnamed modules -->
        <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```